# OpenVPN via OPNsense in Hetzner Network

Tags: openvpn, vlan, hetzner, opnsense

I am trying to set my openVPN server via OPNsense installed in the hetzner cloud in order to get access to the hetzner's internal network.

The hertzner's internal network structure is separated by VLANs (per default https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/networks/connect-dedi-vswitch/).

The given IPs are as follows:

Whole Network: 10.0.0.0/16

```
Cloud System: 
10.0.0.0/24

vswitch: 10.0.0.1

OPNsense1: 10.0.0.2

OPNsense2: 10.0.0.3
```

--

```
Dedicated System:
10.0.1.0/24

DB1: 10.0.1.2
```

I've set up a real basic OpenVPN Server with the following network-settings:

```
Tunnel Network: 192.168.0.0/24
Remote Network: 10.0.0.0/24
```

When connected to the VPN server, I am able to ping 10.0.0.2 but I am not able to ping 10.0.0.3.
OPNsense itself in turn can ping all devices via console.

Unfortunately, I can't use the bridge mode when it comes to the OpenVPN server.

So, does anyone know how to get it work within the internal hetzner network?

Comment: Are you also willing to consider to use WireGuard, here is full fledged tutorial of that from them https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/vpc-with-wireguard-pfsense/